# assign object attribute to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a user, and I want to update the users language:
The Object of the user looks like this:

```
   user: {
      name: "somename", 
      language: 1
    }
```

I now want to change the language ID of the user object, when changing the selected language. Therefor I assign v-model="user.language", but it does not seem to update my users property "language".

Is there any way to have v-model update a property of an object, without having to assign another variable to v-model and then assign this variable to the objects property later on?

```
                  <el-select class="w-100" v-model="user.language">
                    <el-option
                            v-for="lang in all_languages"
                            :key="lang.id"
                            :label="lang.name"
                            :value="lang.id"
                    >
                    </el-option>
                </el-select>
```

Comment: You can also use the `@change` event to dynamically change the `user.language`

Comment: `v-model` should be able to update `user.language` no problem. What is the basis for your conclusion that it isn't being updated?